# jni4net - how to set the absolute path to jni4net.j-0.7.1.0.jar

Tags: java, .net, dll

I use jni4net in my WCF service. in the ctor of the service I try to create BridgeSetup object.

```
        var bridgeSetup = new BridgeSetup(false);
        bridgeSetup.AddAllJarsClassPath(".");
        Bridge.CreateJVM(bridgeSetup);
```

As I understand in this moment jni4ne tryes to generate jni4net.j-0.7.1.0.dll from jni4net.j-0.7.1.0.jar. It tryes to find jni4net.j-0.7.1.0.jar near the jni4net.n-0.7.1.0.dll and can't. So I get next error...

c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\fileprocessingservice\76f0fa69\5db44426\assembly\dl3\4fa263c6\f424b7fa_c8ccca01\jni4net.j-0.7.1.0.DLL

Anybody know how to solve the problem?

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

So, I resolve this problem with the folloving

```
        var bridgeSetup = new BridgeSetup(false);
        bridgeSetup.AddClassPath("c:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\");
        bridgeSetup.AddAllJarsClassPath("c:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\");
        Bridge.CreateJVM(bridgeSetup);
```

But I think that this is not the best way.

Good luck, guys! =)

Comment: That's probably best you could get today. If you are keen to contribute patch for jni4net to improve this drop me email.